# How to check all array indexes in one while loop at the same time Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have an array with 5 size , and I want to assign value from random function if any index doesn't have it.

```
while(positionXtoStart==array1[0] || positionXtoStart==array1[1] || 
      positionXtoStart==array1[2] || positionXtoStart==array1[3] || 
      positionXtoStart==array1[4])
{    
    positionXtoStart = (rand1.nextInt(400) + 1)+30;  
}
```

this solution is ok for small size of array but if i have array with size of 1000, I cant enter 1000 conditions in the while loop.

I tried For-loop with if-else condition in it but the
problem is, I want to check **all array indexes at the same time.**

> Please try to understand what i am asking. I want to check all array index values at the same time **(in one shot)**.

in For-loop, we can check only one value at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, what you're asking is not possible. Even in your code:

```
while(positionXtoStart==array1[0] || positionXtoStart==array1[1] || 
  positionXtoStart==array1[2] || positionXtoStart==array1[3] || 
  positionXtoStart==array1[4])
```

the computer is checking one condition at a time. It's not doing all the conditions at once, like you may think it is. The code you posted is equivalent to the code @Supericy and @Samiam posted.

Unless there's a reason the forloops doesn't work for your case, I would say go with the answers that are posted here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to loop through the array, checking each value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    if (array1[i] == positionXtoStart)
    {
         positionXtoStart = (rand1.nextInt(400) + 1)+30;

         break; // exit the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I asked to check each value at once, in loop, if condition is checking one value at a time.

Comment: i want to check all values at the same time

Comment: @OMAiS you(or computer, or anything) at a given time can only do one thing. Computers can only compare two values at a given time.

Comment: as in a question, u can see. i have 5 conditions using OR . if any one is true than WHILE will do something. 
OR u can tell me solution that how can i enter 1000 conditions in a WHILE. like i am doing 5 conditions

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
    if(array[i] == whatever)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check each entry you have to go trough the whole array. An unordered array in not really suitable for searching trough it. Maybe you should think of changing your data structure into something like a BST so you have a guarantied O(logn) search.

To compare all elements in an unordered array you need linear time.